# Forgot leisheiv basucah. Now what?

Tags: halacha, blessing, mistakes, sukkah

If someone is eating a mezonot food in the Succah, and forgets to say leisheiv basucah, (when) should they make it up?

Say it right now? Just skip it? Make a bracha achronah and restart the meal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Mishna B'rura* 639:48](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=214) says to say it as soon as he remembers so long as he's still at his meal and that, if he hasn't yet said his *b'racha acharona*, he should eat more thereafter; it seems to me to imply that, if he has already said his *b'racha acharona*, he should sit around awhile after "*leshev basuka*".

Comment: Qitzur Shulhhan Arukh, Yalqut Yosef, Orahh Hayim 639:30